# Display correctly a sprite with thread

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, sprite

I'm using a thread to display an animation with a sprite.

```
Explosion e2 = new Explosion(this, x2, y2, explosion);    
new Thread(e2).start();
```

And in the explosion class I have :

```
public void run()
{
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              cursor++;
          }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer(50, taskPerformer);

    while(cursor < (sprite.getNbSprite()-1))
    {           
        timer.start();

        drawExplosion();    
    }
    timer.stop();

    compteur--;

}

public void drawExplosion()
{       
    Graphics g = board.getGraphics();
    board.repaint();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.drawImage(sprite.getSprite(cursor), x, y, this);
g.dispose();
}
```

But during the display I have a problem , between each image of the sprite there is a blank.
Like if the display is twinkling.

How can I have a fluid displaying ?
Thanks

EDIT -----------------------
I've one more question.
In my Board class i've I put my explosion in an ArrayList.
But I've to delete the object in the ArrayList when the explosion thread end.
Do I have an ArrayList to stock all my explosion thread and when a thread end I delete the object in the explosion ArrayList.
public class Board extends JPanel{

```
Mouse mouse;
ArrayList<Explosion> explosions;
Sprite explosion;

public Board() 
{           
    mouse = new Mouse(this);

    explosion = new Sprite(320,320,5,5,"files/explosion2.png");

    explosions = new ArrayList();

    setDoubleBuffered(true); 

    this.addMouseListener(mouse);
}

public void addExplosion(int x, int y)
{


    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        int x2 = (int)(Math.random() * 450);
        int y2 = (int)(Math.random() * 450);

        Explosion e2 = new Explosion(this, x2, y2, explosion);


        explosions.add(e2);

        new Thread(e2).start();

    }

}

public void removeExplosion(Explosion e)
{
    explosions.remove(e);

}


public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    for(int i=0; i<explosions.size(); i++)
    {
        g2d.drawImage(explosion.getSprite(explosions.get(i).getCursorI()), explosions.get(i).getX(), explosions.get(i).getY(), this);
    }

    g.dispose();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swing, you must do everything related to Swing in the EDT.

```
// This actually calls paint() in the Swing EDT  
board.repaint(); 
// This runs on your main thread 
// (Never paint anything outside of the EDT!)
g2d.drawImage(sprite.getSprite(cursor), x, y, this);
```

You see some blinking because there is some painting done on `board` in two different threads and painting two different things.

What you have to do is create a `class BoardWithSprite extend JPanel`
which overrides its `paintComponent(g)` method such that it paints the sprite.

Then you can just call `boardWithSprite.repaint()` and it will do the painting correctly on the Swing EDT.

Comment: Thanks, I move the draw method in my Board class and It's work :)

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be doing many things wrong, including

- making Swing calls in a background thread (your ActionListener/Timer code)
- repeatedly and needlessly calling start on the Timer object. I've no idea what you're trying to do with that bit of code.
- Getting a Graphics object via `getGraphics()` which does not get a persisting Graphics object.

Instead,

- use a SwingWorker or Swing Timer for your sprite animation
- Make all Swing calls on the EDT unless you know from API documentation that the method is thread safe -- edit: you've already been told this in previous answers here.
- Read up in the Swing tutorials on how to do Swing drawing including how to use a BufferedImage and how to draw in the paintComponent method of a JComponent or one of its children (such as a JPanel).

If you're still stuck, then consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I use the timer to wait few second before change the sprite.

Answer (score 1):

The `Timer.start()` method is used to start the timer and should only be called **once**.  It cause the `ActionListener` object to be invoked at the interval specified in the `Timer` constructor.  In your case, it will increment the `cursor` variable once every 50 milliseconds.

You may want to look into a technique called **double buffering**.  This involves using two image buffers to render the images on the screen.  It works like this: instead of drawing the image directly to the screen, you draw it to an in-memory buffer.  You display the frame on the screen **only when you are done rendering the entire frame**.  This helps to eliminate flickering.

For the second frame, you do the same thing, only you draw to the second buffer since the first buffer is currently being used to display an image on the screen.  When you are done drawing the second frame, you then send the *second* buffer to the screen and use the *first* buffer to render the next frame, and so on.

Rendering each frame in memory before displaying it on the screen should help to eliminate flickering.